# How to concat achnor tag in ajax success result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax in mvc.

I want to concat anchor tag in Ajax success result and call java script function click on anchor tag.

my code:

```
success: function (result) {
      if(result.code == 1)
      {
          result.message + '<a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>';
          Message(result);
      }


  },

function Message(response)
{
alert(response.message);//it seem display only my message. not concat anchor tag
}
```

It display only message. doesn't concat anchor tag.

How to concat achnor tag in ajax success result?

Regards,
Jatin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are concating the value but it will not be added in `result.message`.

I guess you need something like this :-

```
success: function (result) {
      if(result.code == 1)
      {
          result.message += '<a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>';
          Message(result);
      }


  },
```

to put space you can put some blank space as shown below :-

```
result.message += '  <a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>';
```

Comment: Hey @Neel thanks for faster response your code is working fine and now how to make some space between message and anchor tag.

Comment: result.message += '  <a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>'; Neel its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
result.message + '<a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>';
```

This line concatenates the message and the link but the result is assigned nowhere.

Try

```
result.message = result.message + '<a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>';
```

Comment: Hey @ibiza thanks for faster response your code is working fine and now how to make some space between message and anchor tag.

Comment: just add one space in the string representing the link, like this :`result.message + ' <a href="#" onClick="return Test();"/>';`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying it in html view you need to put  tag like

```
result.message += '<a href="#" onClick="return Test();">Click Here</a>';
```

Comment: Hey @sujit patil thanks for faster response your code is working fine and now how to make some space between message and anchor tag.

Comment: concat &nbsp; for space before <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why not returning a View("your html here").
And on the client side, just use .append() method and add the html where you want.